# using openTok for app iOS lost connection background mode

Tags: ios, background, chat, opentok

I'm developing an app chat (voice and text) in iOS, and I'm using openTok. When I put the application in background mode (click on home button or block my phone), my connection is lost and I can't  receive more message. 
Is there a way to not lost the connection when I send the app in background or some configuration in xCode for background (like VoIP) or some way for notify the user about a new message?

I hope to hear from somebody soon...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode go to Project->Capabilities->Background Modes and checkmark Audio & AirPlay. This will persists your connection when you background your App.

A full explanation of what you can/cannot do in background modes is at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But, if the user close the app and I need send a message, necessary use APNS right?